# How to write data to a custom field

Tags: entities

I had another question at [Save data to custom field columns using entity_metadata_wrapper](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/save-data-to-custom-field-columns-using-entity-metadata-wrapper) and a similar issue at https://drupal.org/node/2110161, which nobody has been able to figure out yet.

Since entity_metadata_wrapper isn't working for writing custom field values, how can I do this manually?  I've tried the following code, but when I view the node afterwards, the field value is blank.

```
$fieldname = 'field_device_id';
    $query = db_insert('field_data_' . $fieldname)
        ->fields(array(
          'entity_type' => 'node',
          'bundle' => 'equipment',
          'entity_id' => $new_ent->getIdentifier(),
          'language' => 'und',
          'delta' => 0,
          $fieldname . '_esn_hex' => isset($conversion_values['ESN_HEX']) ? $conversion_values['ESN_HEX'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_esn_dec' => isset($conversion_values['ESN_DEC']) ? $conversion_values['ESN_DEC'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_meid_hex' => isset($conversion_values['MEID_HEX']) ? $conversion_values['MEID_HEX'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_meid_dec' => isset($conversion_values['MEID_DEC']) ? $conversion_values['MEID_DEC'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_imei_hex' => isset($conversion_values['IMEI_HEX']) ? $conversion_values['IMEI_HEX'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_imei_dec' => isset($conversion_values['IMEI_DEC']) ? $conversion_values['IMEI_DEC'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_iccid_hex' => isset($conversion_values['ICCID_HEX']) ? $conversion_values['ICCID_HEX'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_iccid_dec' => isset($conversion_values['ICCID_DEC']) ? $conversion_values['ICCID_DEC'] : NULL,
          $fieldname . '_raw_id' => $id,
        ))
        ->execute();
  }
```

This code runs after a submit handler passes in a device id that a user has entered, and converts it to several different formats, which are available in $conversion_values.

There has got to be a way to programmatically write values to custom field columns defined in hook_schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the procedural method is concerned, you would use exactly the same method for a custom field as you would a contrib/core field.

Core field:

```
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' = '<p>Some body text</p>',
  'format' => 'full_html',
);
```

Your custom field:

```
$node->field_whatever[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'esn_hex' => $some_val,
  'esn_dec' => $some_other_val,
  // etc...
);
```

To persist changes to both, use `node_save()` (or `entity_save()`, or whataver helper method the entity you're using provides).

```
node_save($node);
```

That's all you need to do. Manipulating the field tables manually is not recommended, as you bypass a lot of hooks that need to run, cache management, etc.

To use custom fields with an `EntityMetadataWrapper`, you need to go a bit further and describe the field and its columns to the entity module.

This involves adding `property_type` and `property_callbacks` to your field definition in `hook_field_info()`, and providing appropriate callbacks for those. There's a bit more information in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34823/what-does-the-property-type-key-do-in-hook-field-info)